# Split Up String With Two Conditions: "+" and "-" And Keep Signs

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I am using PHP and am trying to split up a string such as this: `3x^3 - 4x^2 + 2x - 3 + 5x^5 - 2x^7` between all the `-` (minus) and `+` (plus) symbols. I have tried using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), but this can only accept one condition (only `-` or `+`, not both).

I have looked at the [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function, and have tried using `"/+|-/"` as the regular expression for the first condition, but it does not work because `+` is not treated as the character "+", but as an operator for regex. How could I split up the string between `-` and `+` using proper regex?

UPDATE: Sahil Gulati, thank you for your response. The regular expression you posted worked perfectly. However, after reading symcbean's comment, I realized I also need to keep the signs. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: `~[+-]~` <-- use that regular expression

Comment: While it is easy enough to split on multiple characters, if your purpose is to parse an expression there is rather a lot of difference between a '+' and '-' and the split operation *removes* the characters. Further, if you are trying to parse an arithmetics expression, you are going to have to work out how to deal with precedence before you start splitting strings on + and -. Maybe if you explained the underlying problem you are trying to solve we could better advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape `+` character by using this `\+`, Here you can use either this `/\+|\-/` or `/[\+\-]/`
here both regex means either `+` and `-`

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='3x^3 - 4x^2 + 2x - 3 + 5x^5 - 2x^7';
$segments=preg_split("/\+|\-/", $string);
print_r($segments);
```

Comment: `/[+-]/` is good enough without escaping. The same for `/\+|-/`

Comment: I usually escape these character for a safe side, but thanks for suggession @zerkms :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question update, it appears that you can go back to `explode()` on each empty space.

Here is the one-liner:

```
$string='3x^3 - 4x^2 + 2x - 3 + 5x^5 - 2x^7';
var_export(explode(' ',$string));
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => '3x^3',
    1 => '-',
    2 => '4x^2',
    3 => '+',
    4 => '2x',
    5 => '-',
    6 => '3',
    7 => '+',
    8 => '5x^5',
    9 => '-',
    10 => '2x^7'
)
```